# How do I indicate path to proxylist when using get_project_settings() in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run my spider from my script.
It runs fine from command prompt and it runs fine from the script if I don't use my proxies (except I get 403's because I'm not using proxies).

I have tried changing my filepath, but none worked.

In settings.py I simply use

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH = 'proxylist'
```

This is my scapy.cfg, I tried changing 'scraper' to scraper.scraper for the heck of it, but didn't work.

```
[settings]
default = scraper.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = scraper
```

This is my project structure

- rascraper

  - scraper

    - spiders

      - **init**.py
      - Spider.py
    - **init**.py
    - items.py
    - middewares.py
    - pipelines.py
    - settings.py
    - scraper
    - scrapy.cfg
    - proxylist

I don't think including the spider is relevant, but this is how I call it (in the same file)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('Acts', artist="eddiem")
    process.start()
```

Why does scrapy not find my proxyfile when calling the settings via get_project_settings()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scrapy.cfg` needs to be moved to it's parent directory.

According to the scrapy docs.

> Though it can be modified, all Scrapy projects have the same file structure by default, similar to this:
>
> ```
> scrapy.cfg
> myproject/
>     __init__.py
>     items.py
>     middlewares.py
>     pipelines.py
>     settings.py
>     spiders/
>         __init__.py
>         spider1.py
>         spider2.py
>         ...
> ```
>
> The directory where the scrapy.cfg file resides is known as the project root directory. That file contains the name of the python module that defines the project settings. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> [settings]
> default = myproject.settings
> ```

Which means the `scrapy.cfg` file should be at least one directory above the the project directory/directory with the `settings.py` file.

Comment: I have changed scrapy.cgf's  location and got it to work by putting my proxylist file within the Spiders folder. Putting it anywhere else, I couldn't figure out what the correct path would be. (Now it's just 'proxylist'). Do you know why that is? I would like to understand properly.

Comment: You put the proxylist inside the spiders folder and not the scraper folder?  But your settings.py file is in the scraper folder right? What folder is your current working directory?